# jQuery + PHP Dynamically Created Content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on an ecommerce site and the products are being dynamically generated with foreach loop, within each product there are product options, when the product option is selected I my intended behaviour is for the price to update.

I have this working, however jQuery is updating every instance of the price on the page and the select option only works for the first item generated. How do I add/bind the jQuery to the object/every product and have the price change on individual basis?

```
<?php 
  foreach($items as $item):
    <?php echo $the_name ?>

    <select id="choose">
      foreach($selection as $select):
        <option value="$some_var" data-value="$the_price">$some_var</option>
      endforeach;
    </select>

    <div id="price"><?php echo $the_price ?></div>
  endforeach;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#choose').change(function (event) {
    jQuery('#price').html(jQuery('#choose option:selected').data('value'));
  }).change();
</script>
```

**Working Code**

After playing about for a while, and taking into consideration the other comments below, this code works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('.choose').change(function (event) {
    var $t = jQuery(this);
    var price = $t.find('option:selected').data('value');
    $t.parents('form').find('.price').html(price);
  }).change();
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use the same "id" attribute on multiple elements. Use "class" instead.

Comment: Is the price a total sum of all `.choose` values, or just the value of the changed selectbox? Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's are unique. Because 'choose' is in a loop, you've got multiple choose ID's, which isn't helping things. Same with the 'price'. So, let's change it a bit:

```
<?php 
    foreach($items as $item):
        <?php echo $the_name ?>
        <select class="choose">
            foreach($selection as $select):
            <option value="$some_var" data-value="$the_price">$some_var</option>
            endforeach;
        </select>
        <div class="price"><?php echo $the_price ?></div>
    endforeach;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.choose').change(function (event) {
        jQuery(this).next().html(jQuery(this).data('value'));
    }).change();
</script>
```

Explanation:

Since you can have more than one `choose`, you then need to do a bit of DOM navigation to get the `price` that is relative to the select. So, whenever a select box is changed it will look for the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element in the DOM tree that is a sibling , which if your code snippet is complete will be the `price` element, and then update the html to that value. One thought though - you may want to use [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/), unless you have HTML in your prices. Also, when you're inside an event (unless you've done something special to rebind the scope), in jQuery `this` will refer to the element that the event fired on. So, `jQuery(this)` will return a jQuery reference to the element that was changed.

Comment: According to what the OP gave, it should just be the value of the changed selection box.

Comment: Ahh.. sorry, I though I was commenting on the OP's question... ignore my comment

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very thourugh and helped me understand the manipulation of the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

      foreach($items as $item):

      <?php echo $the_name ?>

      <select class="choose">
         foreach($selection as $select):

         <option value="$some_var" data-value="$the_price">$some_var</option>

         endforeach;
       </select>

       <div class="price"><?php echo $the_price ?></div>

      endforeach;



    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery('.choose').change(function (event) {
         jQuery$(this).parent().next(".price").html(jQuery('#choose option:selected').data('value'));
       }).change();
    </script>
```